# How to optimize whole folder like with jpegtran?

Tags: command-line, 12.04, software-recommendation, image-processing, batch

Back in Windows I would use jpegtran program to process all of the images in a folder.

However, there doesn't seem to be an application in Ubuntu with UI for performing the same task. Obviously, I should do it from the terminal, but I have no idea how to perform a lossless batch operation. All of the tutorials mention cropping etc., but I don't need those operations.

Therefore, my question is:

What should I type in the terminal to perform lossless optimization (i.e. only strip meta data I guess) of the folder with images (e.g. `ExampleFolder`).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, if you need `jpegtran`, you can find it in the `libjpeg-turbo-progs` package. This has all the optimisation features of its Windows counterpart but you have to use it via the command line and it's frankly, quite a pain to use.

There are other ways of looping over files, but here I'll use `find`. The following will look for `*.jpgs` in the current directory. (Note this is not the same as previous versions of this post, for simplicity)

```
cd /path/with/jpgs
find . -exec jpegtran -optimize -outfile "{}.opti.jpg" "{}" \;
```

If you want it to save over itself, you can. Change the `-outfile` argument to `"{}"`.

Comment: OK, that seems great. Can you explain the following: 1. How does it know that it has to search in photos? Can I point to folder "Example" in Photos? 2. Where did you specify anything about "2010"? 3. I'd prefer it to retain the same name, I guess that this "opti.jpg" tells it to add "opti" suffix.

Comment: @take2 Sorry I've revised this a bit since writing that part. I'll make it make sense.

Comment: You can specify the directory that `find` works in with the first parameter. In the current example, it will just look at the current working directory.

Comment: OK, how would I point to photos/example folder?

Comment: It's probably just simpler to jump into that directory with `cd`, but again, you'd just change the `.` near the beginning to `photos/example`. Note that `find` **will** search subdirectories by default. If you're doing stuff like this, it's safer to move your files into a place that only has the stuff you want to work on.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is with a different tool (`jpegoptim`):

```
$ sudo apt-get install jpegoptim
$ cd /directory/with/my/jpgs
$ jpegoptim *.jpg
19112008152.jpg 2592x1944 24bit Exif IPTC  [OK] 654743 --> 624552 bytes (4.61%), optimized.
19112008153.jpg 1944x2592 24bit Exif  [OK] 516927 --> 503801 bytes (2.54%), optimized.
19112008154.jpg 2592x1944 24bit Exif IPTC  [OK] 943392 --> 911266 bytes (3.41%), optimized.
19112008155.jpg 2592x1944 24bit Exif IPTC  [OK] 919962 --> 894754 bytes (2.74%), optimized.
19112008156.jpg 2592x1944 24bit Exif  [OK] 869388 --> 836059 bytes (3.83%), optimized.
19112008157.jpg 2592x1944 24bit Exif  [OK] 815169 --> 787316 bytes (3.42%), optimized.
19112008158.jpg 2592x1944 24bit Exif IPTC  [OK] 481438 --> 445175 bytes (7.53%), optimized.
19112008159.jpg 2592x1944 24bit Exif  [OK] 686519 --> 660520 bytes (3.79%), optimized.
19112008160.jpg 2592x1944 24bit Exif  [OK] 326367 --> 287568 bytes (11.89%), optimized.
19112008161.jpg 1944x2592 24bit Exif  [OK] 331862 --> 295984 bytes (10.81%), optimized.
```

There are quite a few options:

```
jpegoptim v1.2.3  Copyright (c) Timo Kokkonen, 1996-2009.
Usage: jpegoptim [options] <filenames> 

  -d<path>, --dest=<path>
                  specify alternative destination directory for 
                  optimized files (default is to overwrite originals)
  -f, --force     force optimization
  -h, --help      display this help and exit
  -m[0..100], --max=[0..100] 
                  set maximum image quality factor (disables lossless
                  optimization mode, which is by default on)
  -n, --noaction  don't really optimize files, just print results
  -o, --overwrite overwrite target file even if it exists
  -p, --preserve  preserve file timestamps
  -q, --quiet     quiet mode
  -t, --totals    print totals after processing all files
  -v, --verbose   enable verbose mode (positively chatty)
  -V, --version   print program version

  --strip-all     strip all (Comment & Exif) markers from output file
  --strip-com     strip Comment markers from output file
  --strip-exif    strip Exif markers from output file
  --strip-iptc    strip IPTC markers from output file
  --strip-icc     strip ICC profile markers from output file
```

Comment: I'd prefer jpegtran, since I've seen that jpegoptim is not entirely lossless.